# How to Xpose a model similar to ZBrush?

Tags: axis, zbrush

How to Xpose a model similar to ZBrush?
example: 1) house model with 600 parts. 2) Xpose View to make a flat view. have Each part center pivot and laid out X,Z, axis. 3) Xpose to reassemble.